# Determining size of DOM elements added with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

This is making me cross-eyed

We've created a custom [jquery UI widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget) that builds out a bunch of DOM elements within it's initializer. All I want to do is somehow capture the actual dimensions of these elements when the widget is rendered.

Here's a simple example of adding a p tag to the DOM dynamically and reading its dimensions with jQuery:

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.container').append('<p class="p1">Here is some more</p>');
    console.log($('p.p1').width());
    console.log($('p.p1').height());
});
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/gYusd/7/

That works no problem. However, when we do essentially the same thing in the widget's _create method...

```
this.element.append('<p>Some text</p>');
```

...inspecting those elements dimensions either within _create or in the main jquery function always yields pre-layout dimensions - e.g. p tags have 0 heights, etc.

So I'm trying to understand what's different in these two situations, and if there's a way to reliably determine element dimensions of our jquery widget once it's loaded.

Comment: Do you get this behaviour in both Chrome n Firefox or only Chrome?

Comment: Also, could you share the code you're trying in your `_create` function and `Jquery main function`?

Comment: @Vandesh- both Chrome and FF.` I added code example to the question

Comment: Check the value of `this` in a debugger. That is probably the issue.

Comment: @Robusto- That's not relevant. `this` is the widget instance, I know what it is. The elements get added to the DOM just fine- I'm simply trying to capture their dimensions during the page load.

Comment: might it be because `_create` is called only once and before `_init`. Have you tried moving it to `_init` and checked?

Comment: @Vandesh- good idea but tried and it didn't work